# Oracle in-line view query

Tags: sql, oracle

The commented (/* */) part of this query executes but the whole query am getting problem in /////// part.Please hlep to solve this.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM (

 /*   (SELECT U1.EMAIL, S1.GRNNUM
       FROM RDT_USER U1,
            (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
               FROM RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                    (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                       FROM RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                      WHERE M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND M.LATEST = 1
                        AND (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) S
              WHERE O.FUCODE = S.ORGINATORCODE) S1

      WHERE U1.ORGID = S1.ID)*/ A///////here am getting right paranthesis missing,

    (SELECT U.EMAIL, T1.GRNNUM
       FROM RDT_USER U,
            (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
               FROM RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                    (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                       FROM RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                      WHERE M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND M.LATEST = 1
                        AND (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) T
              WHERE O.FUCODE = T.ORGINATORCODE) T1

      WHERE U.ORGID = T1.ID) B)
 WHERE A.GRNNUM = B.GRNNUM
```

Comment: you need a comma(`,`) after `A`, where you're getting missing paranthesis.

Comment: The commented part is actually getting ignored. If you just remove it from the query you'll get the same error. What do you want to achieve with the `A///////...` part? Remember comments in SQL are preceded by `--`. Also, as Florin commented, if `A` is to be in the `select` clause, you'll need to separate it from the second `select` with a comma.

Comment: that is not commented part to explain you I did like that..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two subqueries/inline views need to be connected in some way. You probably want a cross join -- indicated by the comma between them -- in which case, you can also remove a set of parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT U1.EMAIL, S1.GRNNUM
        FROM   RDT_USER U1,
               (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
                FROM   RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                       (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                        FROM   RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                        WHERE  M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND    M.LATEST = 1
                        AND    (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) S
                WHERE  O.FUCODE = S.ORGINATORCODE) S1

        WHERE U1.ORGID = S1.ID) A,

       (SELECT U.EMAIL, T1.GRNNUM
        FROM   RDT_USER U,
               (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
                FROM   RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                       (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                        FROM   RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                        WHERE  M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND    M.LATEST = 1
                        AND    (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) T
                WHERE  O.FUCODE = T.ORGINATORCODE) T1
        WHERE U.ORGID = T1.ID) B
 WHERE  A.GRNNUM = B.GRNNUM;
```

---

**EDIT** The more I look at your query, the more I see problems with it.

1. Your inline views/subqueries are identical. The only effect cross joining them will have is to increase execution time.
2. Why are you doing cross joins? Inner joins will suffice.
3. Your inner queries are missing some column specs, which you are referencing in outer queries for the join. This won't work.

The core of your query is basically this logic:

```
select grnnum,
       recepientcode,
       originatorcode
from   rdt_goodsreceiptnote
where  actionstatus       = 0
and    latest             = 1
and    sysdate - gendate >= 0;
```

You are then cross joining this with `rdt_organization`, then cross joining that with `rdt_user`; this mess is then crossed with itself, for some reason. This can be *greatly* simplified with inner joins:

```
select rdt_user.email,
       rdt_goodsreceiptnote.grnnum

from   rdt_goodsreceiptnote

join   rdt_organization
on     rdt_organization.fucode = rdt_goodsreceiptnode.originatorcode

join   rdt_user
on     rdt_user.orgid = rdt_organization.id

where  rdt_goodsreceiptnode.actionstatus       = 0
and    rdt_goodsreceiptnode.latest             = 1
and    sysdate - rdt_goodsreceiptnode.gendate >= 0;
```

There's no reason for you to do this twice, in a cross join, so that's it. Much easier, huh?

Answer (score 1):

You need put alias `A` into comment as below:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (

 /*   (SELECT U1.EMAIL, S1.GRNNUM
       FROM RDT_USER U1,
            (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
               FROM RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                    (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                       FROM RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                      WHERE M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND M.LATEST = 1
                        AND (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) S
              WHERE O.FUCODE = S.ORGINATORCODE) S1

      WHERE U1.ORGID = S1.ID) A///////here am getting right paranthesis missing,
*/
    (SELECT U.EMAIL, T1.GRNNUM
       FROM RDT_USER U,
            (SELECT O.ID, GRNNUM
               FROM RDT_ORGANIZATION O,
                    (SELECT GRNNUM, RECEPIENTCODE, ORGINATORCODE
                       FROM RDT_GOODSRECEIPTNOTE M
                      WHERE M.ACTIONSTATUS = 0
                        AND M.LATEST = 1
                        AND (SYSDATE - M.GENDATE) >= 0) T
              WHERE O.FUCODE = T.ORGINATORCODE) T1

      WHERE U.ORGID = T1.ID) B)
 WHERE A.GRNNUM = B.GRNNUM
```